# How to overlay a view on the status bar in ios13

Tags: statusbar, ios13

```swift
fileprivate lazy var netTipWindow:UIWindow = {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: topMargins, width: UIScreenW, height: realheight))
        window.backgroundColor = .clear
        window.windowLevel = .alert
        window.isHidden = false
        window.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        window.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(self)
        frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -(topMargins + realheight), width: UIScreenW, height: realheight)
        return window
    }()
```

My Code works well in ios 12, but it works like the picture.

Also, I tried this code, it makes no difference

```swift
    fileprivate lazy var netTipWindow:UIWindow = {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: topMargins, width: UIScreenW, height: realheight))
        window.backgroundColor = .clear
        window.windowLevel = .alert
        window.isHidden = false
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            window.addSubview(self)
        } else {
            window.rootViewController = UIViewController()
            window.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(self)
        }
        frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -(topMargins + realheight), width: UIScreenW, height: realheight)
        return window
    }()
```

[iOS 13 status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQJ6Z.jpg)

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Same issue but not playing with window in the first place. I've also looked int [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060606/uiwindow-not-showing-over-content-in-ios-13) and play around with `UIWindowScene` but with no luck. Any updates anyone?

Answer (score -1):

this code....

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        // safearea iPhone x, xr ..
        if ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].safeAreaInsets.top > 20.0) {
            return NO;
        }
        else {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```