# UIWindow and it's content not showing in Xcode 11 iOS 13. Getting black screen

Tags: ios13, xcode11, uiwindow, rootviewcontroller

I had Swift project which was developed in Xcode 10.2 and it was working fine. I had migrated my code from Xcode **10.2** to Xcode **11.3**. Since after this my app is not working properly. Whenever I tries to add window it's content is not showing and it's totally back screen.

***I got this error in console:***

**- [Window] Manually adding the rootViewController's view to the view hierarchy is no longer supported. Please allow UIWindow to add the rootViewController's view to the view hierarchy itself.**

Here's my code:

```
    fileprivate(set) var topOverlayWindow         = UIWindow()

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.topOverlayWindow.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(rawValue: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    self.topOverlayWindow.backgroundColor = NSUtility.editVideoThemeColor
    self.topOverlayWindow.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width:  56, height: 45)
    self.topOverlayWindow.rootViewController = KAPPDELEGATE?.window?.rootViewController;
    self.topOverlayWindow.alpha = 1.0
    self.topOverlayWindow.isHidden = false
    self.topOverlayWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: I got the solution. Now it's working fine in iOS 12, iOS 13 from Xcode 11 too. 

In above code I just replace this 
   
self.topOverlayWindow.rootViewController = KAPPDELEGATE?.window?.rootViewController

with below mentioned code

   self.topOverlayWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController() 
                        // Or you can pass reference to any new controller

Rest everything is fine. 


Ref took from here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060606/uiwindow-not-showing-over-content-in-ios-13

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Now it's working fine in *iOS 12, iOS 13 from Xcode 11* too.

In above code I just replace this

```
self.topOverlayWindow.rootViewController = KAPPDELEGATE?.window?.rootViewController
```

with below mentioned code

```
self.topOverlayWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
```

// Or you can pass reference to any new controller Rest everything is fine. Ref took from here:

[UIWindow not showing over content in iOS 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060606/uiwindow-not-showing-over-content-in-ios-13)